# Predicted ability edge case issue

Tags: architecture

I am in the process of creating an ability system with client prediction akin to Unreal Engine 4's Gameplay Ability System.

I found an edge case where the client's tags that are applied from effects become out of sync with the server.

The prediction method I use is the same as detailed [here](https://github.com/tranek/GASDocumentation#4101-prediction-key).

Here is a scenario that illustrates this:

The player has 2 abilities, an ability to unsheathe their weapon, and an ability to sheathe their weapon. Each ability requires a specific tag to activate. For the *unsheathe ability*, it is the **"Sheathed"** tag. For the *sheathe ability*, it is the **"Unsheathed"** tag.

There also exist two effects that apply these tags. The **UnsheatheEffect** applies the **"Unsheathed"** tag and the **SheatheEffect** applies the **"Sheathed"** tag.

The *unsheathe ability* lasts for 1 second and at the end applies the **UnsheatheEffect** and removes the **SheatheEffect**. The *sheathe ability* does the same thing but applies the **SheatheEffect** and removes the **UnsheatheEffect**.

In this scenario, the player has a static ping of 1 second.

0 seconds: The client activates *unsheathe ability*. `Tags {"Sheathed"}`

1 second: The server activates *unsheathe ability*.

1 second: The client finishes *unsheathe ability*. `Tags {"Unsheathed"}`

1 second: The client proceeds to activate *sheathe ability*. `Tags {"Unsheathed"}`

2 seconds: The server finishes *unsheathe ability* and starts the *sheathe ability*.
2 seconds: The client finishes the *sheathe ability*. `Tags {"Sheathed"}`
2 seconds: The client activates the *unsheathe ability*. `Tags {"Sheathed"}`

3 seconds: The client reconciles with what happened on the server as a result of the *unsheathe ability*. `Tags {"Unsheathed", "Sheathed"}`.

The issue is that the client has already gone through the process of removing tags after abilities, but they are soon added back because of the reconciliation with the server. I am really not sure what to do about this, because the client should be in sync with the server, but it ends up just messing up the whole system.